# Inherited method doesn`t change variables values

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding

Inherited method init() doesn't work in new class. A, B, C, D values remain unchanged thus overrided square() method doesn't work either.

Tried moving A, B, C, D into public since in the most examples on the internet variables are there.

Quadrangle`s methods work as intended. But "class Quadrangle is underlined by IDE: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier". Though program doesn't crash.

Also, am I doing override of square() in correct way?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point {
    float x, y;
};

class Quadrangle
{
public:
    void init() // sets coordinates for A, B, C, D
    {
        cout << "Input A coordinates (x, y): ";
        cin >> A.x >> A.y;
        cout << "Input B coordinates (x, y): ";
        cin >> B.x >> B.y;
        cout << "Input C coordinates (x, y): ";
        cin >> C.x >> C.y;
        cout << "Input D coordinates (x, y): ";
        cin >> D.x >> D.y;
    };

    void square()
    {
        // square calculation
    };

private:
    point A, B, C, D;
};

class Rectangle : public Quadrangle
{
public:
    void square()
    {
        // square calculation
    };

private:
    point A, B, C, D;
};
```

English isn't my first and I don`t have an experience at talking about the programming. Sorry if something is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but I guess you should remove the attributes A, B, C and D from your Rectangle class and make those in the Quadrangle class 'protected'

Comment: @StackDanny Not in any way at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Rectangle` defines another copy of each of your member variables:

```
class Quadrangle
{
    ...
    point A, B, C, D;
};

class Rectangle : public Quadrangle
{
    ...
    point A, B, C, D;
};
```

Naturally the methods of `Quadrangle` access `Quadrangle::A`, `Quadrangle::B`, etc., while the methods of `Rectangle` access `Rectangle::A`, `Rectangle::B`, etc., a completely separate set of variables.

Instead you should define your variables only in `Quadrangle` and mark them `protected` (so `Rectangle` can access them):

```
class Quadrangle
{
    ...
    protected:
    point A, B, C, D;
};

class Rectangle : public Quadrangle
{
    ...
    // no variables
};
```

Comment: I didn't catch that. Nice job. That'd do it!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you want to access class members from descendants, then you need to use `protected` keyword, rather than `private`.

Secondly, you do not need to declare same variables in descendants.

In you case you declared 2 sets of variables with same names which is accessible only from corresponding classes.

Answer (score 4):

Your base class `Quadrangle` has no methods to override because none of them are marked with the 'virtual' keyword.
What you now have is known as overloading, which will only work if the type of Quadrangle is known at compile time.

And remember : as a good rule of thumb, if a class has any virtual method make sure the destructor is virtual as well :

```cpp
virtual ~Quadrangle() = default;
virtual void init();
virtual void square();
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't need polymorphism. There's no indication in the question that it's necessary here (except for the OP saying "override" _but_ we should take with a pinch of salt that this usage was strongly intended/understood!).  Also I think you meant _destructor_.

Answer (score 2):

To address the 2nd part of your question: To override in the sense of polymorphism you need to declare both square functions as virtual.